# Unable to solve Cannot find method deleteRow((class)) error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I made a simple script, to send an email based on a condition and then delete that row so that the same email isn't sent again.

However, I'm getting the following error:

InternalError: Cannot find method deleteRow((class)).

Code is below:

```
function ProjectEmailer(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Lines Ready Emailer"));
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange=sheet.getRange("A2:G")  ;
  var data=dataRange.getValues();  
  for (i in data) {
    var rowData = data[i];
    if (!rowData || rowData[0] == "") {break;}
    var emailAddress = rowData[4];
    var emailsubject = rowData[5];
    var emailbody = rowData[6];
    if(rowData[3] === "Lines were written"){
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to:emailAddress,
      subject:emailsubject,
      body:emailbody,
      });
      sheet.deleteRow(rowData[7]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a **datarange** to the deleteRow function. However, it receives an **integer** instead of a **datarange**.
Please, take a look at the [function documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleteRow(Integer)).

Try the following code:
`sheet.deleteRow(7);`

Comment: I figured out what mistake I made. I wasn't passing the rowData[7] since the range was only A2:G instead of A2:H